# JQuery selector not working with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select HTML elements by ID in order to modify their attributes 
but for some reason it is not working. I have defined my elements as:

When I try to select the elements by doing the following I do not get any effect.

```
function handleClick(id){
    var ID =  parseInt(id);
    $("#ID").css({"background-color": "white"});
}
```

However, if I make the call with the following instead I get the desired effect: $("#16").css({"background-color": "white"});

How can I change my code so that I can do the changes based on the id parameter?

Comment: When is `handleClick`, does the `id` element exist in the DOM? Also `"#ID"` is just a string, it doesn't have the value your your variable `ID`. Maybe you mean either `$("#"+ID)` or `$("#"+id)`?

Comment: You are not using variable `ID` anywhere..

Comment: your "ID" is a string in jquery. You should do something like this $("#"+ID).css ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a tag on the page with the `id` of `16` the code should look like this:

```
function handleClick(id){
    var ID =  parseInt(id);
    $("#"+ID.toString()).css({"background-color": "white"});
}
```

So if `16` is passed to the `id` it will run like this:

```
function handleClick("16"){
    var ID =  parseInt("16"); //int id
    $("#"+16.toString()).css({"background-color": "white"}); 
    //will not work because raw ints do not support toSting(). Jquery will look for "#16"
}
```